# Messenger Bot - Read user clipboard

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger-bot

I'm building a app where users can share specific content with one another. I'm trying to make it so when the user has relevant content in their clip board the app automatically asks them if they want to paste it into the conversation.

Is this possible? Where can I find the documentation for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all Messenger Platform only supports page <> user conversations, not user <> user conversations.

Then Messenger Platform is cross-platform, where most likely the majority uses the Messenger app on mobile where you cannot access the content of the clipboard for obvious reasons.

Taking these 2 into account you may want to reconsider your original app idea.